# Using Lodash _.chain() for Conditionals

Tags: javascript, lodash

I would like to use lodash `_.chain()` for conditionals. Is this something that lodash should be used for?

```
if(_.chain(123).isNumber()
               .anotherCheck()
               .anotherCheck()
               .value() {
   // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do somthing like

```
_.chain(123)
    .thru(function(num) {
        return _.every([ // or _.some for any item
            _.isNumber(num),
            _.anotherCheck(num),
            _.anotherCheck(num)
        ]);
    })
    .value();
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need. Cheers.

Comment: This is great! `_.chain(123).thru(function(num) {return _.every([_.isNumber(num),_.lt(num, 200),_.gt(num, 100)]);}).value();`

Answer (score 2):

`chain` does not make sense in this case because `isNumber` is going to return a `boolean`. So `anotherCheck` is not going to get the number but the result of `isNumber`.

One way to use `lodash` for something like this is using `_.every` for example:

```
function testNumber(num) {
  return _.every([_.isNumber(num), num > 100, num % 2 === 0]);
}

function testNumberResult(num) {
  var canUse = testNumber(num);
  if (canUse) {
     console.log(num, 'num is a number greater than 100 and even');
  } else {
    console.log(num, 'num did not pass tests');
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't even think about `_.isNumber()` returning a bool.